# External data in name manager delete! How to simple this? VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

how to simplify this code to remove externaldata_* in name manager.

> ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_21").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_22").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_23").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_24").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_25").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_26").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_27").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_28").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_29").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_30").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_31").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_32").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_33").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_34").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_35").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_36").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_37").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_38").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_39").Delete
>       ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_40").Delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give this a try...

```
Dim i As Long
On Error Resume Next
For i = 21 To 40
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("ExternalData_" & i).Delete
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
```